# react-native-date android datepicker does not work

Tags: android, mobile, reactjs, react-native

[react-native-date](https://github.com/nucleartux/react-native-date)

When I run "react-native run-android", it gives this error

`A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Cannot evaluate module reactdate : Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

Comment: The functionality available via the npm package is now a part of react native as of 0.20.0. At least for the most part. Any reason not to use the react native version?

Comment: I didn't read release notes properly. Thank you.